# ValueError: inhomogeneous shape for scipy.optimize.minimize with matrix in function

Tags: python, scipy, valueerror

I am trying to use pythons scipy.optimize.minimize to find the value of x in a function where the function goes to 0. However, although the final result of the function is a single value, the function does contain a matrix operation, which gives me an error:

```
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "...\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    result = minimize(func, x0 = 15, bounds = [ (0 , 10000 ) ])

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 699, in minimize
    res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lbfgsb_py.py", line 306, in _minimize_lbfgsb
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py", line 263, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 158, in __init__
    self._update_fun()

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 251, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 155, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 137, in fun_wrapped
    fx = fun(np.copy(x), *args)

  File "...\test.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    func = lambda x: example(x)

  File "...\test.py", line 18, in example
    A = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1],

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 145, in __new__
    arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (6,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Below I've put an example function which gives the above error. Is there a way to miniimize this function?

(note that this is an example function, I have no clue if there is actually a solution to this function. My main question is about whether or not there is a solution to the error I get).

I'm using python version 3.10.8.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.linalg import solve

def example(x: float) -> float:
    a = 4
    b = 4*x
    c = 18*np.sin(x)
    d = 14*np.sqrt(1/x)

    A = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1],
                   [0 - 1, 4, 2*x, 0, 0],
                   [1, 3*x-4, 4, 18, 2, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [3*x, 2*a, b, d, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, d, d-c, 0, 0]
                   ])

    b = np.matrix([[0],
                   [0],
                   [b-c],
                   [c/d],
                   [4*a],
                   [b*a-c]
                   ])

    C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 = np.squeeze(solve(A, b))

    val = C1 * np.sin(a * 2) + C2 * c**2 + 4*C3*x**2 + d*C4 + C5*x + C6

    return val

func = lambda x: example(x)
result = minimize(func, x0 = 15, bounds = [ (0 , 10000 ) ])
```

At first I have tried to minimize the function using sympy. However, that took forever and is thus not an option. Theoretically I could (probably) solve this by solving the matrix by hand, writing out each of the functions individually. However, I rather only go there as a last resort, it makes the code quite unreadable, as well as making everything no longer similar to the references I use.

Comment: full error message please!

Comment: Did you even test `example` to make sure it's a valid function?  The error, if you take time to read the full stack, occurs when trying to make `A`.  Try `example(15)`, which is how `minimize` will try to use your function.

Comment: the problem is that `x` is not actually defined and the `lambda` just wraps the `example` function which still requires an argument `x` (which is not defined). So this will fail...  it just happens to fail inside of the `minimize` function so it was a bit less obvious.

Comment: `[0 - 1, 4, 2*x, 0, 0],` has only 5 terms, the other lines to `A` have 6.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.minimize` doesn't pass a float parameter to the function but a 1D array, this leads to an incorrect matrix (e.g. `[[0, 0, array(30), 0, 0]]`). Casting the value solves the issue:

```
def example(x_in) -> float:
  x = float(x_in)
```